# Video player that doesn't stop playing when screen turns off

Tags: android, video, media-player

I have some speech videos and would like to continue playing when screen is off (in other words, continue to play the audio).
Does anyone know of a video player capable of doing this on Android - as I don't want to extract the audio (I have Format Factory).

Device: tablet Sansung Note 10.1 GT-N8000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en)

This player has a 'Background play' option (under 'Player' in the settings) that does exactly what you want. I just tested it on my Lenovo Yoga 10 HD+, it kept playing the audio after I hit the power button to kill the screen.

Answer (score 4):

[VLC for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc)

Audio files are played even when you lock the device. Video files are paused, however, you can play a video file as an audio file, so that you retain the former behavior. Likewise, this implies that you cannot watch the video itself.

Instruction:

1. Go into the video section of VLC.
2. Long-touch a video and select "Play as audio".

Comment: Note VLC now has an option for "Play videos in background" (on the preferences menu). So that will continue playing the audio, when you turn the screen off.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have YouTube Red, you can open it in another browser (Firefox for Android, and Safari for iOS) shown in [this video from Unbox Therapy](https://youtu.be/loljVgbmbfo).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Podcast Addict for this. You just have to go into Settings > Player > Video Player and deselect the Foreground Player option.